# Javascript Array loses data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays

I'm having trouble getting my information into an array in an ajax call, if I alert the information right after I insert it into the array it works fine, but if I do it at the end it alerts unidentified. I made sure that books is declared outside so it doesn't interfere.

```
            var books = [];
        $.ajax({
               url: 'getFolderContents.php',
               dataType: 'json',
               success: function (data)
               {       
                    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
                        var amm = 0;
                        if(data[i].indexOf(".epub") !== -1) {
                            //$('#bTable').append("<td><a id = '" + data[i] + "' href = 'book.html'><img src = 'book.png' width = '100px'/><br/>" + data[i] + "</a></td>");
                            books.push(data[i]);
                            //alert(books[0]) Works if I call it from here, but not at the end.
                        }
                    }
               },
               error: function()
               {
                alert("error");
               }
        });
        alert(books[0]);
```

Comment: ajax is async, so actually alert(books[0]); can be called before ajax filled array. You need to print it inside success method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your

```
alert(books[0]);
```

will be executed while the Ajax call is running and therefore will not have any elements at this point of execution yet. Ajax is asynchronous - while you are doing a request to your PHP script your script continues execution.

Put all actions with `books` in your `success` function.

Another hint: As of jQuery version 1.8 you cannot longer use the parameter `async: false` to create a synchronous "A"jax call. You have to use the callback functions. Have a look at [the docs for $.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: But what if I want to use the array right after the call then ? will I have to put the ajax call inside a seperate function to ensure it completes or will that not work either ? Thanks btw :)

Comment: If you want to use the array put all actions regarding this array into your `success` function (you can either call another function from your success function to make the code cleaner).

Comment: You cannot guarantee the presence of data in your array unless the code using the array has been executed in or called from your success handler. So moving the AJAX call around won't really help. You could put the code you want to execute using the filled array into its own function, and just call that function from inside the success handler function.

Comment: @ajp15243 The reason I wanted to put it inside of an array is to avoid having nested ajax calls. from past experience they have quite a bit of trouble because of the asynchronous nature.

Comment: @Crossman I don't see where a second, nested AJAX call entered the situation. Aren't you just asking why your array didn't seem to have any data in the code immediately following the `$.ajax({...});` call? I just meant you could have a separate function that does stuff with `books` and assumes the array is filled, and just call that function from inside the success handler, since you can't put code that does stuff with `books` immediately after your AJAX call. It was more of an extraneous design suggestion than anything else.

Comment: @ajp15243 I was just stating that I was trying to avoid it from the start, but I got it working with having all my code in the success, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Your array hasn't lost any data; the data hasn't been put in there yet. The 'A' stands for "asynchronous", meaning your success callback hasn't run yet at the time you call the alert.

Put the alert inside your callback instead:

```
        success: function (data)
           {       
                for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
                    var amm = 0;
                    if(data[i].indexOf(".epub") !== -1) {
                        //$('#bTable').append("<td><a id = '" + data[i] + "' href = 'book.html'><img src = 'book.png' width = '100px'/><br/>" + data[i] + "</a></td>");
                        books.push(data[i]);
                        //alert(books[0]) Works if I call it from here, but not at the end.
                    }
                }
                alert(books[0]);
           },
```

Answer (score 1):

Your alert is executing before the success function is called.  Perhaps seeing the same code using a promise will make things clearer.

```
$.ajax( url: 'getFolderContents.php',  dataType: "json"  )
 //the then function's first argument is the success handler  
  .then(function( data ) {

       for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
                        var amm = 0;
                        if(data[i].indexOf(".epub") !== -1) {
                            //$('#bTable').append("<td><a id = '" + data[i] + "' href =                     'book.html'><img src = 'book.png' width = '100px'/><br/>" + data[i] + "</a></td>");
                            books.push(data[i]);
                            //alert(books[0]) Works if I call it from here, but not at the end.
                        }

 alert(books[0]
                    });

});
```

I always feel this syntax makes async stuff make more sense.  Otherwise this code functions exactly like Blazemonger's correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your AJAX call is asynchronous, that's why it is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The alert at the end happens before the ajax success callback, because ajax is asynchronous.